# Architecture to Sandbox the Compilation and Execution Of Untrusted Source Code

Tags: linux, compilation, sandbox, virtualization

The [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/) is a website that lists programming puzzles, then allows users to write code to solve those puzzles and upload their source code to the server.  The server then compiles that source code (or interprets it if it's an interpreted language), runs a battery of unit tests against the code, and verifies that it correctly solves the problem.

What's the best way to implement something like this - how do you sandbox the user input so that it can not compromise the server?  Should you use SELinux, chroot, or virtualization?  All three plus something else I haven't thought of?

How does the application reliably communicate results outside of the jail while also insuring that the results are not compromised? How would you prevent, for instance, an application from writing huge chunks of nonsense data to disk, or other malicious activities?

I'm genuinely curious, as this just seems like a very risky sort of application to run.

Answer (score 1):

A chroot jail executed from a limited user account sounds like the best starting point (i.e. **NOT** root or the same user that runs your webserver)

To prevent huge chunks of nonsense data being written to disk, you could use disk quotas or a separate volume that you don't mind filling up (assuming you're not testing in parallel under the same user - or you'll end up dealing with annoying race conditions)

If you wanted to do something more scalable and secure, you could use dynamic virtualized hosts with your own server/client solution for communication - you have a pool of 'agents' that receive instructions to copy and compile from X repository or share, then execute a battery of tests, and log the output back via the same server/client protocol. Your host process can watch for excessive disk usage and report warnings if required, the agents may or may not execute the code under a chroot jail, and if you're super paranoid you would destroy the agent after each run and spin up a new VM when the next sample is ready for testing. If you're doing this large scale in the cloud (e.g. 100+ agents running on EC2) you only ever have enough spun up to accommodate demand and therefore reduce your costs. Again, if you're going for scale you can use something like Amazon SQS to buffer requests, or if you're doing a experimental sample project then you could do something much simpler (just think distributed parallel processing systems, e.g. seti@home)

Comment: "and therefore reduce your costs" - considering cost reduction why not to use [Ideone API](http://ideone.com/api)? It is ready made and free for small noncommercial projects.

Comment: @Łukasz Kuszner, I was referring ongoing costs with commercial deployments. Once your costs are budgeted in dollars-per-cpu-hour development costs become negligible ;)